# Trying to use mini_magick gem with carrierwave to resize images (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

I had a really tough time trying to get rmagick working so I am trying to get mini_magick to do it instead. The image uploads fine and everything, but I just want it to be resized.

I am using this in image_uploader.rb

```
version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fit => [150, 150]
   end
```

But I get this error message even though mini_magick is installed

```
 LoadError in StaticPagesController#home

cannot load such file -- mini_magick (You may need to install the mini_magick gem)
```

I ran "gem install mini_magick" as well as through the gem file and I know version 3.5.0 of mini_magick is installed. Anyone know how this can be resolved?

I just want images to be resized upon upload through carrierwave.

Thanks

Comment: I know this is a very old post, But could you mark the answer or post the solution that you had found?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the gem is added to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Finally, **restart the rails server**:

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bundler? You need to explicitly specify the gem in the Gemfile for it to be available.

Answer (score 0):

MiniMagick is a Ruby wrapper for a command line application called ImageMagick, so you'll need to install ImageMagick first. You can install ImageMagick through the terminal.

 `brew update 
 brew install imagemagick`

Next, add the `gem 'mini_magick'` to your gem file.
Then run the `bundle`.